# How to make a complex selection of an image over a cylinder top/bottom face and extrude to make a coin

Tags: selection-tools, 3d-printing

Right now I'm trying to sculpt a cylinder face that I have made with 200 vertices and a very subdivided triangle fan cap top, but this gets too laggy for my PC and it's still very ugly.

I wonder if there is a way to make a selection of an image like in photoshop and just bring out that part. I'm trying to make a coin with a logo on it to 3D print.

Comment: can you show an example of the coin face "texture" that you could use, just to aknowledge the complexity? eg: this could be done with displacement.

Comment: @m.ardito - http://imgur.com/a/jYnWa ; this is the image i want on the top of the cylinder. It

Comment: And you want it to be extruded like in real life coin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment above, this could be done with texture displacement, like this:

[image]

of course the provided texture is probably not trimmed enough but you get the idea.

Note: I used a default circle, then filled with about 500 vertices, then subsurfed 5 times... which brings you about 1000x vertices, otherwise your coin face will be much more rough than this... of course it's damn slow.

Another way could be to vectorize the b/w image to svg (eg: use inkscape), then import svg into blender and then extrude... then add a cylinder "body", refine, and try exporting to .stl and similar.

eg., it could end like this

[image]

Note:the vertices count could be *somewhat* smaller in this case, but as usual, the more detail, the best results. In this case you can't easily smooth using subsrf, though... you could need a lot of mesh adjustment to correct (very) bad topology.

You have to find the best settings, it also depends on 3d printer resolution, of course...

Comment: Perfect! this is exactly what I wanted. I spent 2 days finishing it up to my needs and it came out perfect, but I couldn't have done it if it wasn't for you. Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: Good! And in the end which method you used? DId it print well?

Comment: Sorry for such a late response. I used the 2nd method, because it allowed me to modify everything a lot more! Here is the end result after the 3D printing (newer models are more detailed)

https://scontent-sof1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/20030952_1712828935424483_1221814463_n.jpg?oh=6fc4962db5e32a44d0b9af6ba2605848&oe=597C0B21

Sorry for potato quality