# How to add a embossed/debossed logo to a curved surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, geometry, displacement

I’m really having a hard time trying to emboss or deboss a logo / typography on a shape other than a flat plane. For example trying to get a logo on a curved bottle.

[image]

I already asked something similar a year ago, but it was not exactly the same, see here [Emboss or deboss a more complex logo into a mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89610/emboss-or-deboss-a-more-complex-logo-into-a-mesh)

I’ve found that the „easiest“ way for now is to save the logo / typography as a black/white png and then use it to displace the mesh via a displacement modifier. That works well with a flat plane, as I said.

However, if we now take a bottle/cylinder the trouble begins. I don’t know how I can control at which place on the object – a cylinder for example – the logo appears. Do I have to unwrap the cylinder first? Can I somehow control it via texture coordinate nodes where the logo is placed?

Some help would be highly appreciated!

Also, if you have a nice and elegant way on how to place a logo on a curved surface please let me know. I already tried it with attaching the logo to a lattice and then adding this lattice with a shrink-wrap modifier to the object. Problem with this way is, that you often need to subdivide the logo/typography a thousand times in order to get a ok result.

Comment: The answer from your previous question is exactly what you want. This one seems to be about unwrapping your mesh for proper texture use. Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh or any other tutorial on unwrapping.

Comment: No, in my opinion it is not exactly the same answer, otherwise I wouldn't have asked. The biggest difference is that we're now dealing with a curved surface and how to a) add a embossed/debossed logo to it (so that it fits the surface) and b) how I can control the position of the logo if I use a Displacement modifier for example.

So. I see there's a difference, at least for a beginner like me.

Comment: In the answer on your previous question look at the Node screenshot. All the values in Mapping node are 0 for location. Change those and the texture will "move" around your mesh (even around corners if unwrapped correctly). Of course you can also change the rotation and the scale.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to have it in the topology, but just in the render, you can unwrap the bottle and use the logo image as a displacement texture in the material nodes (using Cycles).

If you want to actually emboss/deboss the topology, you could try to import the vector logo, extrude it, curve it (with curve modifier, put it around the bottle and apply the Boolean modifier (Union or difference, in order to emboss/deboss) to the bottle, using the logo as boolean object.